# nativescript-angular: failing to build after installing npm plugins

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I'm new to nativescript/angular, trying to load More items when user scrolls to bottom of list, I tried installing different npm plugins but the app is failing to build with the error:

Execution failed for task ':mergeF0DebugResources'.

> /example/platforms/android/src/main/res/iOS/Info.plist: Error: Unsupported type 'dict'

and I tried to use loadMoreItems() event its not working, along with this loaded, itemTap are also not working.

```
    <GridLayout>
    <ListView [items]="convos" (loadMoreItems)="loadMoreItems()" class="small-spacing">
<ng-template let-item="item">
  <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
    <Image  height="5" width="20%" stretch="aspectFill" loadMode="async" [src]='profilePic[item.to]'></Image>
    <StackLayout width="80%" (tap)="chatOpen(item.to)">
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">  
            <Label [text]="dispName[item.to]" class="medium-spacing" width="70%"></Label>
            <Label [text]="timeSince(item.createdAtTime)" class="medium-spacing pull-right" width="30%"></Label>
        </FlexboxLayout>
        <FlexboxLayout><Label [text]="item.message" class="medium-spacing" width="100%"></Label></FlexboxLayout>
    </StackLayout>
   </FlexboxLayout>
</ng-template>
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need any plugin for that as the list view support this -

**The built-in loadMoreItemsEvent can be used to implement infinite scrolling in your application. Infinite scrolling allows you to load content on demand without the need for pagination.**

**HTML**

```
<ListView [items]="myItems" (loadMoreItems)="loadMoreItems()">
<template let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <Label [text]="item"></Label>
</template>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';`

@Component({
selector: 'list-test',
styleUrls: ['list-test.css'],
template: 'list-test.html'
})

export class ListTest {
public myItems: string[] = [];
public counter = 0;
constructor() {
    this.myItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        this.myItems.push("data item " + i);
        this.counter = i;
    }
}

loadMoreItems() {
    // Load more items here.
    this.myItems.push("data item " + this.counter)
    this.counter += 1;
}}
```

Link - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html#load-more-items

Comment: I tried this but the function is not triggering @Dlucidone

Comment: can you share some code as it's in working fine in my prod build for both iOS and Android.

Comment: <ListView [items]="convos" (loadMoreItems)="loadMoreItems()" class="small-spacing">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout width="80%" (tap)="chatOpen(item.to)">
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">  
                <Label [text]="dispName[item.to]" class="medium-spacing" width="70%"></Label>
            </FlexboxLayout>
            <FlexboxLayout><Label [text]="item.message" class="medium-spacing" width="100%"></Label></FlexboxLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>

Comment: wats the definition you have given in loadMoreItems()?

Comment: loadMoreItems(){
      console.log("Loaded");
  } @Dlucidone

Comment: is this function reachable try invoking it with a button tap

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params, Data } from '@angular/router';
```

I've changed my order of imports to this, it started working. No idea why, If anybody can clarify me on this.